# replacing a list of numbers with a list of their multiplications

Tags: python, list, performance, numpy, multiplication

I have a list of numbers `arr` and a window size `n`.
I want to efficiently (possibly with numpy) compute a new list, where each new element in the list is the multiplication of all the element in the window.
For example, if `arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and `n = 3` I want it to return `res = [6, 24, 60]` and for `n = 2` I want `[2, 6, 12, 20]`.

Comment: interesting, like a kind a window reducer ?

Comment: yeah something like that

Answer (score 2):

My solution involves Pandas.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


arr = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
window_size = 3
rolling = arr.rolling(window_size)
result = rolling.apply(np.prod)
```

The resulting array has the same length of the original array, with the first elements set to NaN.
You can easily drop them with `result.dropna(inplace=True)`.
I hope using Pandas is ok with you, their rolling window functionality is very good!

Answer (score 2):

You could use slicing to do this with a loop if you wanted a non-numpy solution:

```py
from operator import mul
from functools import reduce

def slicer(lst, n):
    i = 0
    while True:
        _slice = lst[i:i+n]
        if not len(_slice) == n:
            break
        yield reduce(mul, _slice)
        i += 1

>>> list(slicer(arr, 3))
[6, 24, 60]
>>> list(slicer(arr, 2))
[2, 6, 12, 20]
```

Alternatively, with a `for` loop:

```py
def slicer(lst, n):
    for i in range(len(lst) - n + 1):
        _slice = lst[i:i+n]
        yield reduce(mul, _slice)


>>> list(slicer(arr, 3))
[6, 24, 60]
>>> list(slicer(arr, 2))
[2, 6, 12, 20]
```

Comment: I want it to be as simple to understand and as fast as possible.
I assume it can be done with a numpy oneliner, if it is possible I want that solution

Comment: @GalSuchetzky putting a requirement on a number of lines isn't always advisable. Enrico's pandas solution could be expressed in a single line, but broken up it reads a bit better

Answer (score 2):

Using SciPy's [`generic_filter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.generic_filter.html) and passing in NumPy's [`prod`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html) as the function to apply to each slice would do:

```py
In [86]: import numpy as np
    ...: from scipy.ndimage import generic_filter as gf

In [87]: def reducer(arr, n):
    ...:     start = n//2
    ...:     stop = len(arr) - (n - 1)//2
    ...:     result = gf(arr, np.prod, n, mode='constant', cval=0)
    ...:     return result[start:stop]

In [88]: arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

In [89]: reducer(arr, 2)
Out[89]: array([ 2,  6, 12, 20])

In [90]: reducer(arr, 3)
Out[90]: array([ 6, 24, 60])

In [91]: reducer(arr, 4)
Out[91]: array([ 24, 120])
```